# What data type use for taxrate field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

What data type should I use for tax rate field in my RoR application. I want it to store only numbers from 0 to 100 and two fixed strings "zw" and "np". Should I use `string` type and parse it to integer when it's number?

Comment: This sounds like two different columns to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's would be pain for me to write a form. I want a selectbox with options to choose from

```TAX_TYPES = [*0..100, "zw", "nw"].freeze```

Comment: Take Two columns 
column1 for integer and column2 for string
save the data in both fields.
create a new method 
def taxrate 
    self.column1+self.column2
end
taxtrate will return you both integer+string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, perhaps, you should think about the tax rate as a *name* of the rate rather than a numeric value.

Create a reference table of tax rates, something like:

```
create table TaxRates (
    TaxRateId int primary key, -- auto_increment/serial/identity
    Name varchar(255) not null unique,
    Value int, -- NULL if not appropriate
    <more columns if necessary>
);
```

The drop-down list can use this table for the names.  Most of the names will be numbers, but that is ok.  The actual numeric value will be in the `Value` field (which you might really want to be a decimal).

Any table that uses a tax rate would have a foreign key reference to `TaxRateId`.